# Click event canvas/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Hey everyone I was trying to make my rectangles clickable.
After it worked i whanted , that when i click on a rectangle that it shows data in the div's. At this moment the data in the canvas div's are manual. 
Is it possible with the script i have to do what i whant or should I start again but make it completly different ???

```
for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    if (x > rects[i][0] && x < rects[i][0] + rects[i][2] && y > rects[i][1] && y < rects[i][1] + rects[i][3]) 
    {
        alert('Rectangle ' + i + ' clicked');
    }
}
```

This is what i had. I don't know  how to change the alert into what i whant.

(For the whole html page )

http://fiddle.jshell.net/f6rLds4g/

Comment: you getting `e.offsetX` undefined. Check http://fiddle.jshell.net/f6rLds4g/2/

Comment: What must i do to show a data in the div en not alert. @ketan

Comment: What kind of data? images, text,html,video,...?

Comment: data from json 

But i try it with text now.
Maybe after text i can find out how to do it with json.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `innerHTML` on the `DIV` will work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    if (x > rects[i][0] && x < rects[i][0] + rects[i][2] && y > rects[i][1] && y < rects[i][1] + rects[i][3]) {
        var container = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = 'Rectangle ' + i + ' clicked';
        document.getElementById("Display").appendChild(span);
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW this is almost what i need. Is it possible to put it in the canvas or in the div. Because when i use it the canvas dissapears :( .

Comment: @S.Oruc I have updated the answer. A new element is created an append to the div so it doesn't remove the canvas. If you need it in the canvas you need to select it and to render text inside.

Comment: What do u mean by select and render ??